# Unable to download package using composer

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

This is my first time using Wordpress with Bedrock  and I use Composer to download my packages instead of manually adding plugins from Wordpress.

I go to https://wpackagist.org/ and try to download Elementor as a plugin using `composer require "wpackagist-plugin/elementor":"3.6.4"`

and I get the error
[image]

> Could not find a matching version of package wpackagist-plugin/elementor. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).

I checked the Elementor package's minimum stability and it is `stable`. Link: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/master/composer.json

In my composer.json I have minimum stability `dev`.
I am currently trying to fix this and find out what `min-stability` represents as this is my first time using these tools.

My `composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "roots/bedrock",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "WordPress boilerplate with Composer, easier configuration, and an improved folder structure",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/bedrock/",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Scott Walkinshaw",
      "email": "scott.walkinshaw@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/swalkinshaw"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben Word",
      "email": "ben@benword.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/retlehs"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "bedrock", "composer", "roots", "wordpress", "wp", "wp-config"
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues",
    "forum": "https://discourse.roots.io/category/bedrock"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://wpackagist.org",
      "only": ["wpackagist-plugin/*", "wpackagist-theme/*"]
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.4",
    "composer/installers": "^2.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4",
    "oscarotero/env": "^2.1",
    "roots/bedrock-autoloader": "^1.0",
    "roots/bedrock-disallow-indexing": "^2.0",
    "roots/wordpress": "5.9.3",
    "roots/wp-config": "1.0.0",
    "roots/wp-password-bcrypt": "1.1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6.2",
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-latest"
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true,
      "roots/wordpress-core-installer": true
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/app/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
      "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "web/app/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "web/wp"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "test": [
      "phpcs"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How about omitting the version? Are you installing v3.6.3 or v3.6.4?

Comment: @Raptor I tried installing both and got same error

Comment: Did you run `composer.phar update` after adding the repository to `composer.json`?

Comment: What version of composer? Maybe you need to be on v2.

Comment: **Cannot reproduce**. With that exact same `composer.json` I'm able to install elementor with the same composer command you show. Works with Composer v1 and composer v2.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 18.04, I get same error as OP when trying to require `"wpackagist-plugin/elementor":"3.6.4"` on composer 1. On composer 2, I still get a similar error: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires wpackagist-plugin/elementor, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.`

Comment: @GrafiCode With the `composer.json` as provided by the OP? I've just copypasted the `composer.json`, run `composer install`, and then copied the require command as shown. It installs fine.

Comment: @yivi as a matter of fact I wasn't using OP's composer.json; when added, there was no error, it worked both on composer 1 and 2.

Comment: Then, as I said, it's not reproducible. The code presented should work.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I using docker for wordpress and php on windows 10 and not WSL or Linux distro . I use volumes for php in /var/www/html which I think is located in Linux . Still not sure if this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste that code into your composer.json like so:

"require": {
"php": ">=7.4",
"composer/installers": "^2.1",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4",
"oscarotero/env": "^2.1",
"roots/bedrock-autoloader": "^1.0",
"roots/bedrock-disallow-indexing": "^2.0",
"roots/wordpress": "5.9.3",
"roots/wp-config": "1.0.0",
"roots/wp-password-bcrypt": "1.1.0",
**"wpackagist-plugin/elementor":"3.6.7"**
},

Then run ***composer update*** from bash.

OR:
you can add it from bash with:
***composer require wpackagist-plugin/elementor:3.6.7***